# Variable cgroups parametres in Docker

Tags: bash, docker, cgroups

I have a problem with setting cgroups in cooperation with Docker. I have my own runnable Docker image

```
docker run exp
```

But the thing that I want is that every user who wants to run my image have to set cgroups parametres before script in image will be run.
I know that there exists something like this:

```
$ docker run -it -m 300M exp
```

but this is not what I'm looking for.
What I really want is something like that. If user types

```
docker run exp
```

then this shows up:
[enter cgroups parametres](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWVbR.png)
and after that image starts up.
I really want to force user to enter his own requirements for cgroups.

And I really dont know how to do this. I thought about some bash script which creates new group in cgroups in every user pc who wants run my docker image but I'm still not sure if it is even possible.

I'll be glad for any help.
Thanks.

Comment: If can I ask, is it possible this `docker run exp` starts up from bash script? If I typed into the docker `docker run exp` and had built bash script with code `docker run -it -m$ exp` where $ is variable and in the bash script I have code for fill the $, so then I think it can works.